# The program is :Take 10 integers from keyboard using loop and print their average value on the screen

Tags: python

Code

```
add = 0

i = 10
while i>0:
    print ("Enter number")
    num = input()
    add = add + num
    i = i-1
print ("average is",add/10.0)
```

Error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `input()` returns a string, not an integer. You need to convert it to `int` using `int(input())`.

Comment: Whatever you enter as input, input function convert it into a string. If you enter an integer value still input() function convert it into a string. You need to do the explicit conversion into an integer in your code.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks